# Keep BroadcastReceiver on configuration change

Tags: android, android-intent, service, location, broadcastreceiver

I'm perhaps thinking this wrong... I'm using a background service in my application to track location updates frequently.

Since there exists a possibility that the location client can disconnect or the connection can fail I have in these methods (in the service) implemented an intent to broadcast a message `new Intent(BROADCAST_CONNECTION_FAILED);` so that when received my app can take appropriate actions (like update the GUI that tracking is turned off and so on)

So what I've done so far is register the connection failed receiver inside my Activity when the GPS service is turned on, but I do not unregister it when my app goes into background (since I want to receive broadcasts in the background). However this creates a problem for me because whenever the configuration is changed (screen rotating etc.) it will try to register the connection failed receiver again (and since it's already registered) it will throw an exception (`Activity com.bla.bla.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver...`)

So regarding this how should I most elegantly solve this?

Comment: UnRegister receiver in the onDestroy and register it in onCreate() so when ever the Config changes occur onCrate again called and reciver is registered..

Comment: @kalyanpvs I don't want to unregister it onDestroy because I want to keep it alive when in the background (as I described)

Comment: A receiver can also act as a standalone receiver, and therefore is not obliged to be bound to an Activity. (you can register these in your manifest)

Comment: @PeterWarbo if your Activity is in the background onDestroy not called..check Activity life cycle once